# Dubai-Oman Common Visa Facility: Departing from the other country

Tags: visas, transit, dubai, oman

Is it possible to arrive at Dubai airport, receive the appropriate seal to enter Oman with the Dubai-issued UAE VoA, travel over land to Muscat, and fly out of Muscat to an airport outside of Oman & UAE?